# Clarification on the definition of a Primitive Root?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I was given the following definition:

If $ord_m(a)= \phi(m)$, then we call $a$ a primitive root modulo $m$.

I am wondering if this definition applies in an "if and only if" sense.

That is, is:

"If $a$ is a primitive root, then $ord_m(a) = \phi(m)$"  a true statement?

Comment: Definitions are iff statements even if they just use the word "if."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the point of a primitive root: it generates the group of units modulo $m$.

Comment: Elaborate? What do you mean "group of units"?

Comment: The set of elements of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ that have multiplicative inverses, e.g. the equivalence classes of the $\phi(m)$ integers relative prime to $m$.